# jquery getScript choking on returned script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 which works OK to return a `JavaScriptResult`. I've tested it with simple javascript.

However, although I can see in firebug that getScript returns javascript to the browser, the code below does not work:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Categories Page</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript('http://localhost:53353/z/categories');
    });   
</script>
</head>    
<body>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <div id="chart_div">
    </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

But if I replace:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript('http://localhost:53353/z/categories');
});
```

.. with the javascript that is returned to the browser when `getScript` is called, then the code does work.

The returned javascript when `getScript` is called is just standard javascript to call a google barchart. The script tags are omitted in the returned script also, since `getScript` adds these.

The question is, why is `getScript` choking on the returned script when I can just copy and paste the returned script and substitute it for the `getScript` section in order to know with certainty that the returned script is not defective, since the page renders correctly when the substitution is made?

OK. Let's forget about MVC.
Just using HTML (and javascript based on the example at 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart ), we have the following which works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Categories Page</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/testscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <div id="chart_div">
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

testscript.js contains only:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460]       
]);
var options = { title: 'Company Performance', vAxis: { title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red' } } };
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); chart.draw(data, options); }
```

But, if we now rewrite the line...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/testscript.js"></script>
```

as...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript('scripts/testscript.js');
    });
</script>
```

...the browser just hangs, even though you can see the contents of testscript.js in the Response in Firebug. Just substituting the contents of testscript.js for something simple like `alert('hello');` allows getScript to work OK, but anything as complex as testscript.js above and getScript just stops working.

Comment: look in network tab of browser console. What is status of request there? If 200, inspect the headers and response body.

Comment: Yes, the status is "200 OK" so I checked the headers and found this:
Request Headers:
Accept text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
...

Response Headers:
Cache-Control private
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 447
Content-Type application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
...

Content-Type differences in the request and response headers? charset? Not sure if I can change these using JavaScriptResult.

The response body is OK, since I used it to copy and paste the javascript into the markup, to test it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the file has not loaded yet, before you start calling the functions in it. 
Can you try the operations in the success function?

```
$.getScript('http://localhost:53353/z/categories', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   if(textStatus == 'success') {
      //do work here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and textStatus == 'success' was true, but the script after '//do work here' didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `$.getScript` for an application I'm working on, to push the loading of a rather heavy date picker script off until it's known to actually be needed.

I found a similar kind of hanging where the browser would just go blank and appear to be loading forever.

I inspected the DOM and what I found was that the date picker script was manipulating the document using `document.write()` calls and, instead of appending to the document, they had replaced the entire document. Getting rid of those fixed this issue in my app, but I later discovered that I already had jQuery UI and that it was silly for me to be using the legacy date picker.

Of course, it has been a while since the question was posted, so the odds are it has all been figured out by now.